# ¿Como se debe usar la etiqueta "if" de struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Estoy tratando de hacer una validación a través de un if de etiquetas en Struts2 pero aun verificando que tienen el mismo valor me devuelve un false.

En el caso de la variable extra tiene un valor String de 00430120074 y en y en presupuesto.auto.CO_BASE7 está asignado el mismo valor en String pero sigue retornando false y ya no le encuentro el sentido de como poder usarlo.

```html
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 selectable-list">
                <ul>
                    <s:iterator value="versiones.VERSIONES">
                        <s:if test="extra==presupuesto.auto.CO_BASE7">X</s:if>
                        <li class="text-center <s:if test="extra==extra">z</s:if>">
                            <a href="getAntiguedad.action" data-seleccion='{"co_version": "<s:property value="coVersion"/>","ds_version" : "<s:property value="noVersion"/>", "co_b7":"<s:property value="coBase7"/>"}' class="ui-user-selection">
                                <s:property value="noVersion"/> (<s:property value="LanzamientoString"/>)</a>
                        </li>
                    </s:iterator>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes modificar el if de la siguiente forma, te falta la #

```
 <s:if test="#extra==presupuesto.auto.CO_BASE7">X</s:if>
```

Este enlace te puede ser de ayuda para el uso de las etiquetas en struts [(etiquetas struts2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007858/whats-the-difference-between-and-signs-in-struts-tags)

Un saludo

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, algo tan, pero tan básico del framework y no lo conseguí por ninguna parte, ni en la documentación de Struts2. Gracias nuevamente.